# Excluding singular curves in NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration

I would like to calculate

```
NIntegrate[1/(x2 x3 + (1 - x2 - x3) (x2 + x3)), {x2, 0, 1}, {x3, 0, 1}, Exclusions -> {x2 == 1/2 (1 - x3 + Sqrt[1 + 2 x3 - 3 x3^2])}]
```

I have tried excluding the singular curve. Any ideas about how to calculate this? Most answers here suggest Exclusions, but alas, it doesn't work. I also tried

```
NIntegrate[1/(x2 x3 + (1 - x2 - x3) (x2 + x3)), {x2, 0, 1}, {x3, 0, 1},Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityHandler" -> None, MaxRecursion -> 120]
```

Any ideas will be helpful.

Comment: Are you sure this is a convergent integral?

Comment: what do you expect the result of integration to be?

Comment: The integrand does not depend on `x1`. Next, `x3 = 1/2; Integrate[1/(x2 x3 + (1 - x2 - x3) (x2 + x3)), {x2, 0, 1}]`produces "Integrate::idiv: Integral of 4/(1+2 x2-4 x2^2) does not converge on {0,1}.". This suggests that the integral under consideration diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Do first integration analytically.

```
int1 = Integrate[1/(x2 x3 + (1 - x2 - x3) (x2 + x3)), {x2, 0, 1}, 
   PrincipalValue -> True, Assumptions -> 0 < x3 < 1]

(*   Log[(1 - 2 x3^3 + Sqrt[1 + (2 - 3 x3) x3] + 
     x3 (3 + 2 Sqrt[1 + (2 - 3 x3) x3]))/(
     2 x3^3)]/Sqrt[1 + (2 - 3 x3) x3]   *)

NIntegrate[int1, {x3, 0, 1}]

(*   3.51586   *)
```

**Edit**
Numerical test yield the same result.

Do a two -step numerical integration, regarding x3 as a parameter for the first NIntegrate.

```
nint2[x3_?NumericQ] := 
   NIntegrate[1/(x2 x3 + (1 - x2 - x3) (x2 + x3)), {x2, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> "PrincipalValue", 
   Exclusions -> {(x2 x3 + (1 - x2 - x3) (x2 + x3)) == 0}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 100, WorkingPrecision -> 30]

pl = Plot[nint2[Rationalize[x3, 0]], {x3, 0, 1}, 
      WorkingPrecision -> 25, PlotRange -> {0, 30}]

NIntegrate[nint2[x3], {x3, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 25] // Timing

(*   {48.016, 3.515860858034190463653627}   *)
```

Comment: Up to [lWiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) , the principal value of a multidimensional integral is defined only in the case of the isolated singularity of the integral. According to `ContourPlot[
 x2 x3 + (1 - x2 - x3) (x2 + x3) == 0, {x2, 0, 1}, {x3, 0, 1}]` , there is a singular line in the case under consideration. It's unclear to me whether the improper integral under consideration converges.

Comment: The integral with `Integrate ` is not a multidimensional integral. x3 is regarded as a parameter. You have only a point singularity with positions depending on parameter x3. Integrate recognizes this.

Comment: Also `NIntegrate[int1, {x3, 0, 1}]` performs `3.51581 - 3.79881 I` in version 12.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: That must be an error in version 12.0. I'm working with version 8.0,  `Plot[int1, {x3, 0, 1}] ` shows result is plausible.

Comment: Two-step numerical integration confirms the analytical result. See Edit to my answer.

Comment: @user64494 Note that the principal value is (properly) applied only to improper integrals that diverge; if they do not diverge, there is no need. That said, Akku14 is assuming that the representation of the double integral by the iterated integral is valid. The principal value depends on a choice (a standard one for the Cauchy PV, but one nonetheless), and it’s a bit like rearranging the terms of a conditionally convergent series. I’m not in a position to investigate this integral further right now, but Akku14’s approach probably ok. It’s another question whether divergent is a better answer.